# Maximum likelihood estimator and confidence interval

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

Let $\theta$ be an unknown constant. Let $W_1,…,W_n$ be independent exponential random variables each with parameter $1$. Let $X_i=θ+W_i$.

First, I need to find $\hat\theta _{ML}(x_1,\ldots ,x_ n)$. I know the likelihood functionis  $L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(\theta|x_i)$, but I am not sure what $f(\theta|x_i)$ look like.

The second question is to construct a 95% confidence interval of the particular form $[ \hat\Theta -c, \hat\Theta ]$ for $n=10$, where $\hat\Theta = \min _ i \{  X_ i \}$ and c is a constant that I need to choose.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hints: See Question 693070. (Enter in search box on this site.) $X_i$ have a 'shifted exponential distribution'. (See Wikipedia.) Also $\min_i(W_i)$ is an exponential with rate n (mean 1/n). Is it stated that $\theta > 0$? Please edit any progress into your question. I'll look back later.

Comment: @Bruce: Thank for your hint, that post is very informative. The original question doesn't mention the scope of $\theta$.  I think even for $\theta<0$, the derivation is still same. I didn't figure out how to construct a confidence interval yet. I guess It is something like $\hat{\theta} \pm \frac{1.96}{\sqrt{nI_1\left(\hat\theta\right)}}$, but how to solve this when $\hat\Theta = \min _ i \{  X_ i \}$, I have no clue. Anyway, the answer will be issued in two days. I will keep update.

Comment: Re CI, can you find dist'n of min from dist'n of $W_i$s? The CI you suggest in your note is not of the requested form.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(X1,…,Xn)$ and $x=(x1,…,xn)$. To find $\hat{\theta }_{ML}$, we first find $f_X(x;θ)$. Since the $W_i$'s are independent, so are the $X_i$'s. Hence,$$\displaystyle  f_ X(x;\theta )\displaystyle  = \prod _{i=1}^{n}f_{X_ i}(x_ i;\theta )\displaystyle  = \begin{cases}  \displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^{n}e^{-(x_ i-\theta )}, &  \mbox{if } x_ i \geq \theta ~ ~ \forall i, \\ 0, &  \textrm{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Note that this quantity is nonzero only if $θ$ is no greater than each of the $x_i$'s. Moreover, $e^{-(x_ i-\theta )}$ is greater when $θ$ is closer to $x_i$. Therefore, this quantity is maximized when we push $θ$ as high as possible while keeping it no greater than each of the $x_i$'s. This means that $\hat\theta _{ML}(x) = \min _ i x_ i$ (Any larger choice of $θ$ would give $f_ X(x;\theta )=0$.)

For the second part of question, we wish to find $c$ such that ${\bf P}(\hat{\Theta }-c \leq \theta \leq \hat{\Theta }) \geq 0.95$.Since the $X_i$'s are independent, we have

${\bf P}(\hat{\Theta }-c\leq \theta )= {\bf P}(\min _ i\{ X_ i\} \leq \theta +c)$
$= 1-{\bf P}(\min _ i\{ X_ i\} \geq \theta +c)$
$= 1-\prod _{i=1}^{10}{\bf P}(X_ i\geq \theta +c)$

$= 1-\prod _{i=1}^{10}{\bf P}(W_ i\geq c)$
$= 1-\prod _{i=1}^{10}e^{-c}$
$= 1-e^{-10c}.$

To have a 95% confidence interval, we require $1-e^{-10c}\geq 0.95$.